# Problem with powerline-shell in fish

Tags: 14.04, fish, powerline-plugin

I use console fish with powerline-shell. Does anybody know why I have this bug? These strange characters.

[image]

Comment: Show us the output of `type fish_prompt`

Comment: What do you mean "type fish_prompt". But in bash I also has this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I made like this:

> wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
>
> mkdir -p ~/.fonts/ && mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.fonts/
>
> fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts